# Why does Perl open() documentation use two different FILEHANDLE styles?

Tags: perl, filehandle, bareword

The [documentation for the open function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) shows the syntax of `open()` as:

- open FILEHANDLE,EXPR
- open FILEHANDLE,MODE,EXPR
- open FILEHANDLE,MODE,EXPR,LIST
- open FILEHANDLE,MODE,REFERENCE
- open FILEHANDLE

Down in the examples they have places where a normal $-prefixed variable is used for the file handle:

```
open(my $fh, "<", "input.txt")
```

and also examples where a bareword is used:

```
open(FOO, "|tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'");
```

One question is what is the name of each style as in "I am using *_*_ for a filehandle" in each case? The other is, **why did they start using bare words** for `open()` in the documentation? It appears to be the later uses all don't involve normal filename `open()`s. Is the $-prefixed form not acceptable in those instances?

Comment: great question, I have always been vexed by that syntax

Comment: Kinda annoying to do `open(STDOUT, "| less")` in any other way than that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The bareword form is, essentially, just historical legacy for backward compatibility. Using a lexical variable is pretty much always The Right Thing To Do in new code.

→ incidentally, `$x` is a *lexical scalar variable*, where `FOO` is, as you said, called a bareword

**Details/Digression**

Just for completeness, as @Joe_Z pointed out in the comments, the lexical filehandle objects are “relatively new,” as a part of the rather major rewrite between Perl 5.005 and 5.6 (they even gained whole orders of magnitude in that version number…).

However, technically, the bareword `FOO` (or, e.g. `STDIN`) is interpreted in a separate namespace just for filehandles. Since there isn't a sigil (like `$ @ % &`) for the filehandle namespace, there are only two ways to reference a filehandle in that namespace:

- You can refer to it in the indirect-object slot of certain functions, like `print`, who will (behind the scenes) infer that a bareword must refer to a filehandle, for historical reasons;
- You can use a typeglob, like `*FOO`, which refers to “anything in any namespace which happens to be bound to the symbol `FOO`.

Note that in some languages, like C or Scheme, a single symbol has no type sigils, and so all symbols can be bound only in one way (e.g. one cannot have a variable named `printf` and a function named `printf` in C … generally), whereas in Perl or (e.g.) Common Lisp, the same symbol `foo` can be bound to many different things; the distinction is that Perl actually requires you to use sigils to disambiguate “which `foo` you mean” in most contexts. `$foo`, `@foo` = `@foo[ $x .. $y]`, `$foo[ $n ]`, `%foo` = `@foo{ $k1, $k2 }` = `$foo{ $k }`, `&foo` and the like.

By using barewords as filehandles, though, you lose some abilities:

Significantly, in order to bind them locally or lexically (instead of globally), you need to bind *every* symbol in every namespace, because there is no sigil available. Thus, `my $foo` and `my @foo` can live in two different scratchpads (scopes), where perhaps one outlives the other; but `my *foo` would include both of these, as well as the filehandle `foo` (and potentially other obscure corner-cases, like `format` specifiers, although I wouldn't swear to it).

It's also immensely difficult to pass a bareword-style filehandle into a function, and the like.

Basically, barewords inherit all of the downsides of global scope and have none of the advantages of lexical variables.

`perldoc perldata` has a nice section on **Typeglobs and Filehandles** which probably explains these things a bit more clearly, as well. I don't have my copy handy, but I believe the Camel goes into more detail on the subject, as well.

Comment: +1: Using lexical file handles is 'the way to do it' even though it's Perl so TMTOWTDI (there's more than one way to do it).

Comment: coz I am a bit old skool I have occasionally used glob style filehandles in answers and invariably get negative comments about this :) Agree that lexical filehandles are better but it's a hard habit to break!

Comment: Lexical filehandles were introduced back around perl 5.6.  There's still a lot of perl code floating around (especially where I work) that dates back to 5.00x, though.  It's good to know about both syntaxes for maintenance purposes.  I think these days, the older bareword filehandles should be confined to a 'legacy' section in the docs, except maybe `<STDIN>` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

As BPRocock said, `my $x` is preferred these days, whereas `FOO` is considered obsolete because `FOO` is a kind of global variables so it might conflict with names used in another place. There is another reason `$x` is encouraged: `$x` will be automatically `close`ed at the end of the scope.