# Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[1] in substitution iterator

Tags: perl

I am trying to run this program that I wrote and I keep getting an error message that states the following

> Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[1] in substitution iterator at
>   ./replaceName.pl line 22.

since the value is the name that is passed from the command line and is the second argument I am not sure what is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;


@FILES = glob("*.txt");

foreach my $file(@FILES){
    if( !defined($ARGV[2]) ){
         $outfile = "$file.modified.txt";
    }
    else {
        $outfile = $ARGV[2];
    }

    open FILE, "< $file" or die("File not found");
    @lines = <FILE>;
    close FILE;

    open OUT, ">", $outfile;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        $line =~ s/YourName/$ARGV[1]/gi;
        print OUT $line;
    }
    close OUT;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that arrays are indexed from 0 in Perl, and the elements of @ARGV do not include the program name.  You should probably be using `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`.  You can check this by printing out the values of the array — index and value at the index.  See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): _The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the script. $#ARGV is generally the number of arguments minus one, because $ARGV[0] is the first argument, not the program's command name itself. See $0 for the command name._

Comment: thank you I was counting the program as the first argument. changed the 1 to a 0 and works great now

Comment: yes I changed that when I changed the other because i realized that there would never be a 3rd argument

Comment: I'd recommend using the `strict` pragma, and declare variables with `my`. Also, using bareword filehandles is obsolete. See [Why declare Perl variable with “my” at file scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334008/why-declare-perl-variable-with-my-at-file-scope) and [Why does Perl open() documentation use two different FILEHANDLE styles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376148/why-does-perl-open-documentation-use-two-different-filehandle-styles) for more information..

Comment: It looks like you are looking for the `-i` command line switch: `perl -pi.modified -e's/YourName/Foo/gi' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that arrays are indexed from 0 in Perl, and the elements of `@ARGV` do not include the program name. You should probably be using `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`. You can check this by printing out the values of the array — index and value at the index.

See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> The array `@ARGV` contains the command-line arguments intended for the script. `$#ARGV` is generally the number of arguments minus one, because `$ARGV[0]` is the first argument, not the program's command name itself. See `$0` for the command name.

Note that this means that if you run:

```
perl script.pl something or-another
```

the `@ARGV` array has two entries: `something` and `or-another` in elements 0 and 1 respectively.  Similarly if the script is executable:

```
script.pl something or-another
```

If you check `$ARGV[2]`, you will be using the default file name with either of the invocations shown — change the 2 to a 1.  Also, you should be able to move the test and assignment to `$outfile` outside the loop, and only open that file just once.  At the moment, you zap it for each new file, so effectively you only process the last file.