# How to go one up folder level using perl?

Tags: perl, directory

I'd like to know to search sub-folders if I'm already in the subdirectory.

ex: ..build/clean/test/subfolder <-----

i've already scripted on how to get to test but can't figure out how to go into the subfolder.

The script looks something like this:
[Directory Handle in Perl Not Working Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61539302/directory-handle-in-perl-not-working-properly)

```
sub response {
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    print "Investigating $arg directory below:-\n";
    opendir(my $DIR, $arg) or die "You've Passed Invalid Directory as Arguments\n";
    my $size = 0;
    while(my $fileName = readdir $DIR) {
        next if $fileName =~ /^\./;
        my $path = File::Spec->catfile( $arg, $fileName );
        if( -d $path) {
            say "Folder1($arg, $fileName)"
        }
        $size++;
    }
    closedir $DIR;  
    if($size == 0) {
        print "The $arg is an empty directory\n";
    }
}
```

This is the sub folder

```
sub Folder1
{
  my $prevPath = shift;
  my $receivedFolder = shift;
  my $realPath = "$prevPath/$receivedFolder";
  my $path = File::Spec->rel2abs($realPath);
  print "$path\n";
  print "$receivedFolder Folder Received\n";
  foreach my $folder (@folder)
  {
    opendir(DIR, $path) or die "You've Passed Invalid Directory as Arguments\n";
        while(my $file = readdir $DIR) {
            next if $file =~ /^\./;
            my $path1 = File::Spec->catfile( $folder, $file );
            if( -d $path1) {
                say "Folder2($folder2, $file)"
   }
      closedir(DIR);
    }
```

The sub 2 folder

```
sub Folder2 {
      my $prevPath1 = shift;
      my $receivedFolder1 = shift;
      my $realPath1 = "$prevPath1/$receivedFolder1";
      my $path1 = File::Spec->rel2abs($realPath1);
      print "$path1\n";
      print "$receivedFolder1 Folder Received\n";
      opendir(DIR, $path1) or die "You've Passed Invalid Directory as Arguments\n";
            while(my $file = readdir DIR) {
            print "Current Folder has $file file\n";
           }
     closedir(DIR)
}
```

I'd like to read the files inside of sub 2 folder. However, i keep going back to the main directory using the sub 2 folder.

```
my @arg = ('clean');
my @folder = ('logs');
```

However, inside the build directory there is also a logs folder. It will be re-directed to there instead of the ../clean/test/logs

Comment: Please clarify where you were before, and what steps you've taken. It's better to post your code.

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are trying to achieve. Please don't reference some external resource as *"something like this"*. Instead include your specific code and highlight the specific problem you have in this code.

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't very clear. Asking clear questions isn't easy, but it's a skill well worth taking the time to master. Imagine that you knew nothing at all about your problem. How could you explain it so that it's obvious what you mean. Something like this perhaps - "I'm in this directory (...) and I want to examine the files in this directory (...). The output I want looks like this (...). Here's my current code (...). I think the problem is in the line I've marked with a comment."

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding everyone! I'll try to make my questions a little bit clearer form now on. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For working with paths, I'd strongly recommend [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny).

```
use Path::Tiny 'path';

my $path = path "/home/tai/Documents/";

for my $child ( $path->children ) {
   print "$child\n" if $child->is_file;
}

my $parent = $path->parent;
print "PARENT: $parent\n";
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, the system can't locate path/tiny.pm. Should I install a package or something?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to install Path::Tiny.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps something like following code snippet can clarify possible approach to the problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $dir = '.';

folder_dive($dir);

sub folder_dive {
    my $folder = shift;
    
    say "In folder: $folder";
    
    for ( glob("$folder/*") ) {
        say "directory  $_"  if -d;     # if we got a directory
        say "file      $_"   if -f;     # if we got a file
        say "\ta file"                  if -f;
        say "\ta link"                  if -l;
        say "\ta socket"                if -S;
        say "\ta pipe"                  if -p;
        say "\ta block device"          if -b;
        say "\ta char device"           if -c;
        say "\ta text"                  if -T;
        say "\ta binary"                if -B;
        say "\treadable"                if -r;
        say "\twritable"                if -w;
        say "\texecutable"              if -x;
        say "\towned by user"           if -o;
        say "\treadable by real user"   if -R;
        say "\twritable by real user"   if -W;
        say "\texecutable by real user" if -X;
        say "\towned by real user"      if -O;
        say "\tzero size"               if -z;
        say "\tnonzero size"            if -s;
        say "\tsetuid"                  if -u;
        say "\tsetguid"                 if -g;
        say "\tsticky bit set"          if -k;
        say "\tisatty is true"          if -t;

        folder_dive("$_") if -d;        # if we got a directory     
    }
}
```

Documentation [Perl File Test Operators](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-file-test-operators/)